# Instantiate an object that stores a reference of another object (inaccessible)

Tags: javascript, oop, reference, undefined

I'm a C# developer and my girlfriend started studying JS.
Although I don't like this language, I try to help him with the objects.

I want to access my 'Season' object from the 'Serie' object which stores a reference to it, but impossible and I don't understand.

I'm not used to being assisted in a programming language, so much by dynamic typing (although C# can do it)

```
class Serie
 {
   constructor(title, season, year)
   {
     this.title = title;
     this.season = season;
     this.year = year;
   }
 }

class Season
{
  contructor(number, episode)
  {
    this.number = number;
    this.episode = episode;
  }
}

class Episode
{
  constructor(title, duration, hasBeenWatched)
  {
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.hasBeenWatched = hasBeenWatched;
  }
}

let episode1 = new Episode("I'am s**", 45, false);
let saison1 = new Season(1, episode1);
let serie1 = new Serie("The Story of Tau", saison1, 1999);

document.querySelector('#first-episode-info').innerText = `Série: ${serie1.title}
Saison: ${serie1.season.number} 
  1 ${serie1.season.episode.title}
          ${serie1.season.episode.duration} min
          ${serie1.season.episode.hasBeenWatched ? 'Already watched' : 'Not yet watched'}
${serie1.year}`;
```

thank you

I want to access the properties of my 'Season' object from another object

I did a lot of research on the internet but I can't find the solution (the evolution of the language changes the syntax)

Please understand that I have no experience in this language.

Comment: Your modeling is backwards. An Episode belongs to a Season (which contains multiple episodes), a Season belongs to a Series (which contains multiple seasons).

Comment: This is example code without arrays.

Currently the series contains a season which itself contains an episode, it doesn't seem to me to be upside down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo.

```
class Season
{
  // contructor -> con(s)tructor
  constructor(number, episode)
  {
    this.number = number;
    this.episode = episode;
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel ashamed, thank you

She used 'CodePen' and he did not mention this error

Comment: Typo is indispensable for us!

Comment: I guess `contructor` will just be seen as a custom method. And since `constructor` is not mandatory, it will not be seen as an error.

Comment: @Kokodoko In this case I could not have called the default constructor with arguments

Comment: That's something weird about javascript, I agree. You won't get an error in your IDE if you call a function/constructor with the wrong amount of arguments.